# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a strange problem with a multi-line graph.  The graph depicts data from a mysql database where new rows are added in 5 second intervals to simulate "live" data.  The graph is then updated in 5 second intervals when the data is re-pulled from database.

The "streaming" stops and starts - with 3 of these errors every time the updated data pulled in:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
 d3_json 
 respond
```

The data is applied to each path/line as follows:

```
 var parameter = svg.selectAll(".parameter")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "parameter");

 parameter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

..then updated data read in in 5 second intervals and graph updated and transitioned accordingly:

```
 d3.json("LiveData.php", function(error, data) 
 {      
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key ==  "testSource_id"; }));
    data = data.map( function (d) { 
    d.testSource_id = +d.testSource_id; 
    d.dateTimeTaken = parseDate(d.dateTimeTaken);
    d.reading = +d.reading;
    d.parameterType = d.parameterType;
    d.parameter_id = +d.parameter_id;
    return d;
 });

data = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.testSource_id; }).entries(data);

x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, function (d) { return  d.dateTimeTaken; }); }),
d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.dateTimeTaken; }); })]);
y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, function (d) { return d.reading; }); }),
d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.reading; });})]);

var newparameters = svg.selectAll("g.parameter")
     .data(data);

newparameters
     .select( "path.line" )
     .transition() 
     .ease("linear")
     .duration(750) 
     .attr( "d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })

svg.select(".x.axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .ease("linear")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.select(".y.axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .ease("linear")
    .call(yAxis);
```

I don't know if this is caused by the way I'm transitioning the path/line or could it be something to do with how the data is pulled in from database?  Can anyone help?

Comment: line 3 : `data = data.map( function (d) { ` close this function somewhere ;)

Comment: Forgot the include all the closing brackets in the code above but they are all there in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when the data returned by accessing the URL passed to `d3.json` is not valid JSON. In your case, I guess `LiveData.php` is returning HTML instead of JSON. It could also be a generic 404 or some other error page.